# SQL-Script to Automatically build pallets

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have code that I am using to call out how many pallets an item would be able to build. The issue I am having is I cannot figure out how to then automatically build pallets based on this number.

For example, if I have an item that can build 3.50 pallets, then I would want that to go into a new table that will then call out Pallet #1 and then a unique name, Pallet #2 then a unique name, Pallet #3 then a unique name. There will then be left over of .50.

I would want to then look in the category and find a ITEM that could fit with the .50 pallet item and try to make a whole pallet. In the table below, the remaining .50 of ITEM '1111' would be paired with ITEM '3333' which is .350 to then make Pallet #4, this process would then loop and find all the other combos based on the category to make the closest full pallet.

Ideally I would like the first pallets to be made on anything greater then 1, by giveng them a unique name, then using the leftovers to combine with other leftovers(items <1) to make other potentially full pallets, with a threshold of between 1 and .85:

```
ITEM  CUBIC_INCHES  PALLETS  CATEGORY  RANKING
1111  100,000       3.50     HIGH_TOP   1
2222  50,000        1.75     LOW_TOP    1
3333  10,000        .350     HIGH_TOP   2
4444  5,000         .175     LOW_TOP    2
```

My code that I am using to make this table is:

```
SELECT
ITEM
,CUBIC_INCHES
,CAST(CASE WHEN CUBIC_INCHES=0 THEN 0 
ELSE (CUBIC_INCHES)/28,571.42 END AS DEC(38,4)) AS PALLETS 
,CATEGORY
,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CATEGORY ORDER BY CUBIC_INCHES) AS RANKING
FROM TABLE_1
```

Comment: That's hard, search for a *bin packing* algorithm.

Comment: Hi @dnoeth I am getting very close to figuring this out for what I need to do, my question is, if I am using a rolling sum amount, is there any way to break the amount once it is >=106,000. So if the SUM is 50,000+50,00 and then the next value is 10,000 then the rolling sum will break and start again at 10,000 since adding 10,000 will be greater then the 106,000 threshold. Thanks for all your help as always,.

Comment: You can't do what you want using a cumulative sum. You need either a Recursive Query (ok, if the number of rows per pallet is low) or a While-loop in a Stored Procedure (better when the number of rows per palet is high)